# Failed to load resource error for images?

Tags: html, css, image, carousel, open-source

After I load my files to cyberduck (an open source) and open my website, the images I used in my carousel are not there and this error shows in my file source. I referenced the images in my CSS file using Background: `url("....jpg")`; and this worked fine in my live previews. What can I do to make them visible on my website?
CSS:

```
.slide1 {
   background-image: url("/photoshop/photoPopcg3feg.jpg");

}
```

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkpxv.png)

Comment: isn't the folder named "portfolio", and not "photoshop" ?

Comment: I have a photoshop folder with my images inside. Everything works fine in the live preview, but the image aren't there when I find my website by url.